# Importing makehuman figure and joining

Tags: import, makehuman

Imported figure direct into blender 3.4.1 using the Import human tab. Human comes in as seperate bits pic1. When i join the seperate bits together pic2 is the result. Not quiet what I want.

[image]

[image]

[Man 01](https://workupload.com/file/vjBqdGJqVdU)

Comment: I don’t see the brown meshes in the unjoined version. Something about joining us making them visible. Did you hide them in viewport (not with the H key)?

Comment: I have attached the file Man01, its on workupload because of the size. This figure is just imported direct from makehuman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you combine multiple meshes, it only keeps the last object's modifiers, all the others are removed. In this case, the "My Man 001.Body" has a Toggle Visibility Helper which is hiding a lot of vertices. These vertices became visible when you joined the meshes together.

To avoid this problem, with the "My Man 001.Body" selected, apply the modifier before you join the meshes:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much.